# Java, assert file equals

Tags: java, performance, equals

I want assert to files using char by char comparation. 
What the best way to do this? Without 3rd part libraries. Which file-reader is most performance for this?

Comment: How big are the files? If they are small enough then simply loading them into memory and comparing the `byte[]` with the appropriate assertion tools would probably be the easiest way. If they can be larger, then that won't work, of course.

Comment: That should easily fit in memory. Note: two files can have different bytes, but have exactly the same characters. ;)

Comment: And since the post is tagged with 'performance': on Java 7 you should possibly check both are the same size prior to reading (if I'm not wrong java.nio.file.Files.size(...) was introduced in Java 7).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure what the objection to 3rd party libraries is... no need to re-invent the wheel.

I've found the open-source and widely used [apache.commons.io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) method `FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2)` is pretty good - here's the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#contentEquals%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29).

Comment: is there a java 7 implementation for this function?

Comment: @Thomas - no. Java 7 had been out for almost a year when this question was asked, and as the answer indicates, this requires a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using Google Guava library then you can use:

```
Files.equal(file1, file2);
```

From the [docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#equal(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)):

```
Returns true if the files contains the same bytes.
```

Comment: There is no [equals](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html).

Comment: @wener Fixed, it was `equal`

Answer (score 1):

For small files (up to a few MB), streaming I/O will yield little benefit, so you might keep things simple:

```
Arrays.equals(Files.readAllBytes(firstFile), Files.readAllBytes(secondFile));
```

If you want to use different encodings, you can also decode the bytes into characters:

```
boolean equal = new String(Files.readAllBytes(firstFile), firstEncoding).equals(
                new String(Files.readAllBytes(secondFile), secondEncoding));
```

This only requires Java 7.